# Change CSS property from existing value with Stylus

Tags: html, css, stylus

I have a set of styles like this one:

```
&.blue
  background #189cd8
  &:hover
    background lighten(#189cd8, 10%)
```

I wonder if it's possible not to set that color the second time for hover state but somehow take it from the parent, like `background lighten(parent(background), 10%)`? I know I can use variables but here I just want to refer to the color of parent so don't want to use them.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Stylus' property lookup feature:

```
&.blue
  background #189cd8
  &:hover
    background lighten(@background, 10%)
```

From http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/docs/variables.html :

> Property lookup will “bubble up” the stack until found, or return null if the property cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using
background: inherit;